# Affecting a QDialog From A QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I would like to affect a QDialog from a separate thread, I have to do two things:

```
dialog->show();
dialog->raise();
dialog->activateWindow();
```

As far as I understand, these are events and thus MUST be done in the main thread event loop.  I think I achieve this with `QApplication::postEvent` within in the `QThread::run()`.  Could anyone confirm?

Second, I would like to display an image which was processed in that separate thread.  I think I need to subclass my dialog class and write a thread safe `setImage()` function, which is then called by `paintEvent()`... However, this seems like it's impossible.  I can't block the paintEvent with a `QMutex::unlock()`?  Could anyone offer some suggestions?

---

`QApplication::postEvent(dialog, new QShowEvent());` did not work.

This is the solution for calling slots (as functions) from a seperate thread:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(dialog, "show", Qt::QueuedConnection);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(dialog, "raise", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

... Still working on `activateWindow()` and `QThread` safe functions.

So for the `QImage`, it is a QPaintDevice.  Supposedly it is thread safe.  My approach would've been to have a class member `QImage` that is set within the thread.  Then painted later.

Note, that the below approach is as good, if not better though.

Comment: I would avoid passing the dialog pointer to the thread and connect signals from an QObject in the other thread instead. For activateWindow, you'd need to write your own slot that just calls activateWindow().

Comment: Hey Frank, any particular reason why? Also, just to confirm, you're saying instead of using `invokeMethod` use `emit SIGNAL` in the `QThread::run()`.  Where SIGNAL has been properly connected earlier in the construction of the QThread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a clearer way to do what you want:

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    ...
public slots:
    void showImage(QImage img);
    ...
}

void Dialog::showImage(QImage img);
{
    setImage(img);
    show();
    raise();
    activateWindow();
}

class Thread : public QThread
{
    ...
signals:
    void imageReady(QImage);
}

void Thread::run()
{
    QImage img;
    /// image processing stuff

    emit imageReady(img);
    ...
}


Thread *thread = new Thread;
Dialog *dialog = new Dialog;
connect(thread, SIGNAL(imageReady(QImage)), dialog, SLOT(showImage(QImage)));

thread->start();
```